# jquery showing html tags instead of formatting them when brought in using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, entities, custom-data-attribute

I have some data stored in my database such as

```
&lt;b&gt;Availability:&lt;/b&gt;
```

I am then echoing this out into 'data-promo' attribute PHP using html_entity_decode

```
<a href="" class="button" data-promo="<?php echo html_entity_decode($mytext); ?>"></a>
```

In my Jquery file. I want to click the above button and then show the text in the '#key' div.

```
$('.button).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  promo = $(this).attr('data-promo');
  $('div#key').html(promo);
});
```

This all works except the value that it renders and displays in the '#key' div as

```
<b>Availability</b>
```

Instead of displaying the tag, I simply just want it to format output.

Comment: May I ask why you want to load button values from a database? I'd say that is quite a resource intensitive approach. Also, can't you add the bold property to the .button class?

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: Each anchor tag is a link to a product. The data-promo contains info about the product. This way it gives an instant response when the user clicks the anchor and the promo text appears instantly rather than waiting for it to load in. It is a chunk of text with different formatting, not just bold thats why I cant just add a class

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to decode using PHP and insert it in the attributes. That will make your HTML malformed. Keep it encoded and use JS to decode it. So try this:

```
$('div#key').html(promo).text();
```

Comment: Did you change your PHP to this: <?php echo $mytext; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`$('div#key').text(promo);`

Comment: When I try that, it changes them back into html entities

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes, Working and checked

```
<?php

    // we got this from db, in your case
    $mytext = "&lt;b&gt;Availability:&lt;/b&gt"

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Script Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    // example

        $(function() {
            $('.button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                promo = $(this).attr('data-promo');

                    $("#key").html(promo).text();

                });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="" class="button" data-promo="<?php echo html_entity_decode($mytext); ?>">Test</a>
    <div id="key"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is still not working. I read something about the kind <meta charset="" /> having something to do with it. Does anybody know anything about this?